# Why does my QEMU/KVM virtual machine not start after CentOS 7.7 update?

Tags: centos, qemu, virsh

After an automatic update of CentOS to version 7.7 on Sep 17 2019 my QEMU/KVM virtual machines do not start when I reboot the hypervisor server.

Trying to start the VM by hand gives this error:

```
# virsh start mygreatvm
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: no connection driver available for <null>
```

Trying to list currently defined VMs (the VMs in questions are set to start by default (autostart) on every boot so they should at least appear here):

```
# virsh list
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: no connection driver available for <null>
```

There are no error messages in system logs and neither in `/var/log/libvirt/qemu/*.log`.  The libvirt daemon seems to run fine and does not complain about the non-started servers in `/etc/libvirt/qemu/autostart/*xml`:

```
# systemctl status libvirtd
● libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-09-18 16:42:30 UTC; 2min 49s ago
     Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
           https://libvirt.org
 Main PID: 1817 (libvirtd)
    Tasks: 16 (limit: 32768)
   CGroup: /system.slice/libvirtd.service
           └─1817 /usr/sbin/libvirtd
Sep 18 16:42:30 server systemd[1]: Starting Virtualization daemon...
Sep 18 16:42:30 server systemd[1]: Started Virtualization daemon.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The updates in CentOS 7.7 include an update to QEMU which needs a new package to be able to start QEMU/KVM virtual machines.

```
# yum install libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu
```

Then the virtual machines can be started right away (no reboot necessary):

```
# systemctl restart libvirtd
# virsh list
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 1     mygreatvm                      running
 2     mygreatvm2                     running
 3     mygreatvm3                     running
```

Some CentOS hypervisors might have this package already installed; there will be no failures on these machines but the package was not necessary in the past.